# Why it's a compile time error to return a class as widget rather than the method?

Tags: flutter

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _buildBar() => Bar();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Bar(), // Compile-time error
      appBar: _buildBar(), // Works
    );
  }
}

class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => AppBar();
}
```

When I assign `Bar()` to `appBar`, it gives a compile time error but when I assign `_buildBar()`, it just works. In both the cases, `Bar()` and `_buildBar()`, I'm returning a regular `Widget` and not a `PreferredSizeWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because appBar must implements [PreferredSizeWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html), meaning that it should know its own size before the build process.

When you use the Bar() directly the widget can't know its own size before the build to run. When you call the function that returns the Bar(), its own build already runned and the widget knows its own size.

Comment: I already knew about the first paragraph. Coming to the second one, I am not running the app, it's just a compile time error, `build()` method doesn't know anything about what other methods are doing. It's an error shown by the compiler not by the VM itself.

Comment: The Dart analyzer can infer what is coming out of the function and because it will return a Widget with know size (after the inner build method), it passes. When using the Widget itself, the analyzer infers that its size will only be known after running the inner build but it will only occurs simultaneously with the outer build method, poping the error. The two keys here are the Dart analyzer and the function that must be completed before returned.

Comment: Talking about the method part, Dart analyzer knows that the method is returning a `Widget` (both method return type and body depicts that), and analyzer also knows that the  `appBar` can only be assigned a `PreferredSizeWidget` and not a regular `Widget`. So, there should be a compile time error when assigning the method to `appBar`.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#what-is-soundness Dart analyzer can do much stuff without compiling. The main point is the inner and outer build methods of the widget tree. The Function will always enforce the inner build to run before returning. The widget directly encapsulated will run its own build simultaneously with its parent build.

Comment: I totally understand that and this is what I am pointing out, the inner `build()` method is returning a `Widget` which `appBar` doesn't accept still it's not an error.

Comment: I'll try some code on Dartpad and return for further discussion.